# Having two jPlayers on a page at the same time. Problem

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, jplayer

I've got a little site mockup here: http://designsweeter.com/live/tg/

I'm using jPlayer HTML5 audio/video. The problem is that it's in the wordpress loop and when you click the bottom one, the top one starts as well, and vice versa. How can I ensure each jPlayer plays its own audio song?

The play and pause comes from this snippet:
    $("#button .button").bind('mousedown', function() {
        $(this).bind('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
            onClick();
        });
    });

```
$("#button .button").bind('mouseup', function() {
    $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
    onClick();
});


function onClick() {        

    if(status != "play") {
        status = "play";
        $("#button").addClass( "play" );
        player.jPlayer("play");
    } else {
        $('#button .circle').removeClass( "rotate" );
        $("#button").removeClass( "play" );
        status = "pause";
        player.jPlayer("pause");
    }
};
```

I'm assuming I'll need to use php and setup a variable for each post ID, which is in Wordpress by default. But how can I insert the post ID into the Javascript so that when I click the play button in #post-1, it plays THAT jPlayer audio, and when I hit the play button in #post-2, it plays the post 2 audio. It looks like a scary mixing of javascript and php, any help?

ETA: The new idea:

```
// play/pause

$('.button').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('id');
    onClick()
});


function onClick() {        

    if(status != "play") {
        status = "play";
        $(this).attr('id').addClass( "play" );
        player.jPlayer("play");
    } else {
        $(this).attr('id').removeClass( "rotate" );
        $(this).attr('id').removeClass( "play" );
        status = "pause";
        player.jPlayer("pause");
    }
};
```

http://designsweeter.com/live/tg/wp-content/themes/twentyten-five/js/zen.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can bind click function to a class, and in function you can chech $(this) variable, for id or something else.

e.g.

HTML:

```
<div class="button" id="button-1">A Button</div>
```

...

JS:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('id');
  ... play music of id ...
});
```

EDIT:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    onClick($(this).attr('id'));
});


function onClick(id) {        

    if(status != "play") {
        status = "play";
        id.addClass( "play" );
        player.jPlayer("play");
    } else {
        id.removeClass( "rotate" );
        id.removeClass( "play" );
        status = "pause";
        player.jPlayer("pause");
    }
};
```

Comment: But the person I'm building for isn't php savvy. So I need the ID attribute to be automatically appended, he can't set the attribute, it's made by wordpress through <?php the_ID(); ?>

How can I set the ID of each Zen player in Javascript with <?php the_ID(); ?>???

I need something like this:

$("#button<?php the_ID(); ?> .button").bind('mouseup', function() {
    $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
    onClick();
});

Comment: How can I make each ID unique, but include that uniqueness in my javascript?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that, but one thing is to iterate through all button divs, append id to a button, and same id to control.

Use $('.button').each as in [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Just ETA'd your first idea. Doesn't work, maybe I don't understand it too well. Take a look at what I wrote.

Comment: Player is just jPlayer beneath, it doesn't really matter. Status is what is used to see if the player is going or not to determine if the button should play or pause.

Comment: @Igoris Azanovas: please update your answer instead of adding that much code to a comment.

Comment: As i understand now, there are many posts, that have their own buttons, which you need to track if they have been clicked ( music is playing), and when you press other button, the first music stops, and other music starts to play.
I don't know jPlayer, but for buttons, my suggestions should work, just needs a little bit more tuning to make jPlayer work.

Comment: Yes. Right now, they all just play and pause, unified. Each player has the same class of .zen, but each player has a different id of #zen1, #zen2, etc.

I need .zen to style the player, and #zen<?php the_ID(); ?> to initialize it and its functions.

I've been trying for hours, no dice.

Comment: I did some tuning, and it OUGHT to work, but it does not. I've posted the full js file at the bottom of my initial question in an edit, please take a look. Thank you!

Comment: I'm making progress, but I'm stuck with adding this line, replacing "$(".button")" with "id". It breaks it.

Comment: Got it figured out, finally! It was just a jPlayer firing issue, the button was working fine. I tried it with a different audio player, worked perfectly! Just required a bit more time to get it to work with jPlayer is all. Strangest problem ever.